# Correlation of particle patterns, mutual density and basic statistics

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am a postgrad student, who managed not to see any statistics in his Maths and Physics undergrad degree (am I the only one surprised by this ?).

Anyway, I wanted to ask if someone could explain the underlying edit:(algebra) of how one goes from eq.2.62 to 2.63 and 2.64 in the attached images ? I just don't see how/why "|u" part is sometimes included, and sometimes not (not sure how the hell the algebra works here). I assume the notation "|u" is supposed to mean a conditional average. i.e. the ensemble average of those two values at a certain u...

When I try to do the "straightforward mathematical manipulation" I can cancel out some of the terms with some nasty assumptions about statistical algebra, but I end up with:

(nV) (nV_{m}) - (nV) (n \delta V)  +  (nV) (n \delta V |u) instead of 2.64... (Where brackets are meant to represent triangular brackets (doesn't let me use them for some reason).

I assume 2.65 is just some kind of definition I am yet to find in "crash course in stats" type of lecture notes.

[image: The mutual density is given by 2.61]

[image: Continuing derivation]

[image: Motion of tracer particles through the measurement volume.]

Comment: The word you're looking for there is algebra, rather than arithmetic. $|u$ after a term indicates that the thing being discussed is conditional on the value of $u$ (read it as 'given u'). Its absence indicates an unconditional equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Brain not functioning anymore.

So is it possible to combine something that's conditional and make it unconditional, and the other way round ? I don't see how the authors simply discard |u...

Comment: Also, I manage to work through a similar problem without a conditional average appearing, page 218 in here if anyone will be bothered looking this up:

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nh0S42qf2mEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: There are a variety of theorems that relate conditional and unconditional quantities. For example, the various "Law of total <something>" are one set of examples.